# Is there a way to git add changes in the currently active file in VS code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I often only want a commit to be in reference to a specific file I've updated. I find myself grabbing the file path and running git add {filepath} a lot. Is there a VS code shortcut or some sort of zsh script I can use to get the current file path from the command line?

Comment: use the SCM tab and click the `+` button next to the file, enter a commit message and commit

Comment: The closest I got was changing the copyRelativeFilePath shortcut and then git add {cmd+c}

Answer (score 0):

you can use the '.' like `git add .` it will add the file/files that have changes at that point of time, then you can just `git commit` it. Thus not needing the full path.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This would add all of my changes to other files as well. I am looking to isolate commit message to one file when I have changes across multiple files.